# Powershell start-process where-object

Tags: powershell

i need start-process where are present a specific file on folder.
i try but not controll the file name, the process start Always

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\prova\pippo\pgm\prova.dttX | Where-Object filename -CLike -InputObject C:\prova\pippo\ -value "pippo*.csv"
```

Comment: So you only want to run `Start-Process` if a file at wildcard path `C:\prova\pippo\*pippo*.csv` exists? If that csv file doesn't exist, you don't want to call `Start-Process` - is that correct?

Comment: Start-process runs in the background and you can't pipe from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `Test-Path` with an `if` condition rather than `Where-Object`:

```
# if any csv file which's name starts with `pippo` exists in `C:\prova\pippo\`
if (Test-Path 'C:\prova\pippo\pippo*.csv') {
    # start the process
    Start-Process -FilePath C:\prova\pippo\pgm\prova.dttX
}
```